# How to redirect the user after registered in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce, I want to redirect the user to My welcome page after registered and using `[woocommerce_my_account]` shortcode. Can I do it without customize the code please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`woocommerce_registration_redirect`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/f6526d72a72e3e2b110ed6c0f7b18329239c6667/includes/class-wc-form-handler.php#L919) hook a and the [`get_page_uri()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_uri) function if you know the ID of your welcome page. (Or you could just hard-code the URL if you prefer)

```
function so_33172484_redirect( $url ){
    $welcome_page = 99;
    $welcome_url = get_page_uri( $page_id );
    if( #welcome_url ){
        $url = $welcome_url;
    }
    return $url;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'so_33172484_redirect' );
```